# Separate and append values from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this: `["demo", "4532t78"]`

It came from two steps:

```
var userInfo = $.parseJSON(JSONallUserInfo);
console.log(userInfo.available_client_ids); // gives me `["demo", "4532t78"]`
```

How do I separate this array further so I can, for example, append each value to a select?

Comment: Can't you simply use subscripts? (`userInfo[0]` will be `"demo"` and `userInfo[1]` will be `"4532t78"`)

Comment: Maybe, but this is a little new to me. Probably very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean that your array represents a value / text pair, or a set of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array elements can be accessed by subscript. Thus, `userInfo.available_client_ids[0]` will evaluate to `"demo"` and `userInfo.available_client_ids[1]` will evaluate to `"4532t78"`. You can then use these expressions to create your `select` elements. It can also be done as a loop where you vary an index from 0 up to but not including `userInfo.available_client_ids.length`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < userInfo.available_client_ids.length; ++i) {
    console.log(userInfo.available_client_ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a JSON string that looks like:

```
{
    available_client_ids: ["demo", "4532t78"]
}
```

Right now you're directly logging the available_client_ids property, which contains an array. One thing you can do to make this easier to work with is to assign that property to a variable:

```
var clientIds = userInfo.available_client_ids;
```

Then you can iterate over that, since it's just an array:

```
// Using Array.prototype.forEach
clientIds.forEach(function(id) {
    // do something with the id here, for example append to another string
    console.log(id);
});
```

You could also look at using the Array methods `map` and `reduce` (or the equivalent in a functional library like Underscore.js) to build a string directly from the array.

Also, since it sounds like you're using jQuery for other stuff it makes sense to use $.parseJSON, but you should be aware that there are builtin JSON methods for parsing and serializing strings and objects in modern browsers, in case you need to work with JSON but don't have jQuery available.

Answer (score 1):

Elements inside arrays can be accessed with their index, starting from `0`.

```
var myArray = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

var firstElement = myArray[0];
```

`firstElement` will be the string `'zero'`.

Some reading material:

- [`Arrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [`For loops`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Full documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through each element and append them to a `<select>`.

```js
var userInfo = ["demo", "4532t78"], 
    dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');

userInfo.forEach(function(el) {   
  var option = document.createElement('option'); 
  option.textContent = el; 
  dropdown1.appendChild(option);  
});
```

```html
<select id="dropdown1">
</select>
```